# Event target value is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is this wrong?

```
<input
    id="url"
    type="text" className="form-control"
    value={url}
    placeholder="https://example.com"
    onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => this.setState({
        url: e.target.value
    })}
/>
```

I'm getting: `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`

**Note:** There is nothing wrong with the code `e.target.value`. That does return the correct value. My question is what is the proper "type" for this event, because `React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>` does not have the property `event.target.value`.

Comment: that means you cannot use ``e.target.value``, should be ``e.target.somethingelse``

Comment: @DonaldWu yes I understand that. `e.target.value` does exist. That's just basic JS Event. I'm asking what the event type is

Comment: I think you need to pass in (e,data) to the onChange function. The data parameter holds the value of your element.

Comment: @Prasanna, no there is nothing wrong with `event.target.value`. It holds the value alright, and works fine. It's just the IDE warning that is annoying that i'd like to fix. I want to find the "right" type for this event.

Comment: I printed the `e.target` value but couldn't see any `value` in it. But if it works , one should not fret over small things. :D

Comment: I wonder why in your case React.FormEvent is generic, while in [react.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/36d40a63a05b5cb3413737fbdf7c9a2a26f211fd/react/react.d.ts) it is not. Anyway, question [why-is-event-target-not-element-in-typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900077/why-is-event-target-not-element-in-typescript) suggest to cast `e.target` to `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: Found the correct [react.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/react/index.d.ts) where `React.FormEvent` **is** generic. Looks like you can say `e.currentTarget.value`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `e.currentTarget.value`. I didn't even have to explicitly type `e`.

`currentTarget` will always be the element you bound the event to; `target` is what you actually clicked on. For more details see http://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't either. At least, in 2020 :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `e.target.value` You should use `(e.target as HTMLInputElement).value`.

The property `value` is not defined in `EventTarget` type but defined in `HTMLInputElement`.

I used [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#type-the-event) as a reference.