# Typescript: React event types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What is the correct type for React events?

Initially I just used `any` for the sake of simplicity. Now, I am trying to clean things up and avoid use of `any` completely.

So in a simple form like this:

```
export interface LoginProps {
  login: {
    [k: string]: string | Function
    uname: string
    passw: string
    logIn: Function
  }
}
@inject('login') @observer
export class Login extends Component<LoginProps, {}> {
  update = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>): void => {
    this.props.login[e.target.name] = e.target.value
  }
  submit = (e: any): void => {
    this.props.login.logIn()
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  render() {
    const { uname, passw } = this.props.login
    return (
      <div id='login' >
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder='Username'
            type="text"
            name='uname'
            value={uname}
            onChange={this.update}
          />
          <input
            placeholder='Password'
            type="password"
            name='passw'
            value={passw}
            onChange={this.update}
          />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.submit} >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What type do I use here as event type?

`React.SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>` does not seem to be working as I get an error that `name` and `value` do not exist on `target`.

More generalised answer for all events would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 382, accepted):

The [SyntheticEvent](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/14d95eb0fe90f5e0579c49df136cccdfe89b2855/types/react/index.d.ts#L1167) interface is generic:

```
interface SyntheticEvent<T> {
    ...
    currentTarget: EventTarget & T;
    ...
}
```

(Technically the `currentTarget` property is on the parent [BaseSyntheticEvent](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/14d95eb0fe90f5e0579c49df136cccdfe89b2855/types/react/index.d.ts#L1142-L1158) type.)

And the `currentTarget` is an intersection of the generic constraint and  `EventTarget`.
Also, since your events are caused by an input element you should use the `ChangeEvent` ([in definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/14d95eb0fe90f5e0579c49df136cccdfe89b2855/types/react/index.d.ts#L1207-L1209), [the react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#form-events)).

Should be:

```
update = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    this.props.login[e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value
}
```

(Note: This answer originally suggested using `React.FormEvent`. The discussion in the comments is related to this suggestion, but `React.ChangeEvent` should be used as shown above.)

Comment: What is a good spot to read about all the common event types? Unable to find anywhere.

Comment: React event types? They are all described in the [events page in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

Comment: I get 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElements'  (TS v2.4)

Comment: @Falieson Weird. If you do `let obj: HTMLInputElement; console.log(obj.name)` is it ok or do you get an error?

Comment: This still gives me the following error. 

"Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'."

Comment: @tomhughes what is the version of the react.d.ts that you are using?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Using React 16.2 with @types/react 16.0.40.

Both are the latest version of their respective packages, should the version numbers match?

Comment: @tomhughes I do not get this error (with the code in my answer: `update = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement)...`) using the same  version of `@types/react`. I'll need to see your code.

Comment: I've copied your code in to my project directly and it gives the same error within VSCode. The same applies with both the code below from @Edwin and chamilton.

I'm running TypeScript 2.7.2 installed as a local package if that makes a difference.

Comment: @tomhughes This is weird. I upgraded to the same tsc version (though it shouldn't matter) and everything works fine for me. Create a new question with your code and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152226/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166403/discussion-between-tomhughes-and-nitzan-tomer).

Comment: If I use `React.FormEvent` or `React.SyntheticEvent`, I always get a type error that `e.key` is not allowed.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I think that `e.key` is only part of keyboard events.

Comment: If you'd like to understand why `target` doesn't work see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61490090/1213041

Comment: Y'all, you need to use `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` this will fix your name, value undefined error

Answer (score 72):

The problem is not with the Event type, but that the EventTarget interface in typescript only has 3 methods:

```
interface EventTarget {
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
    dispatchEvent(evt: Event): boolean;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
}

interface SyntheticEvent {
    bubbles: boolean;
    cancelable: boolean;
    currentTarget: EventTarget;
    defaultPrevented: boolean;
    eventPhase: number;
    isTrusted: boolean;
    nativeEvent: Event;
    preventDefault(): void;
    stopPropagation(): void;
    target: EventTarget;
    timeStamp: Date;
    type: string;
}
```

So it is correct that `name` and `value` don't exist on EventTarget. What you need to do is to cast the target to the specific element type with the properties you need. In this case it will be `HTMLInputElement`.

```
update = (e: React.SyntheticEvent): void => {
    let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.props.login[target.name] = target.value;
}
```

Also for events instead of React.SyntheticEvent, you can also type them as following: `Event`, `MouseEvent`, `KeyboardEvent`...etc, depends on the use case of the handler.

The best way to see all these type definitions is to checkout the .d.ts files from both typescript & react.

Also check out the following link for more explanations:
[Why is Event.target not Element in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900077/why-is-event-target-not-element-in-typescript)

Comment: ps. looks like my type definition file is a bit outdated as it doesn't show the generic SyntheticEvent<T> interface. The answer from Nitzan Tomer is better.

Answer (score 52):

To combine both Nitzan's and Edwin's answers, I found that something like this works for me:

```
update = (e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>): void => {
    let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.props.login[target.name] = target.value;
}
```

Comment: this.props.login[target.name] = target.value;
??? are you changing the props :o

Comment: Just copying the line from the original question so that the answer makes sense to the OP.

Answer (score 52):

I think the simplest way is that:

```
type InputEvent = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
type ButtonEvent = React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>;

update = (e: InputEvent): void => this.props.login[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
submit = (e:  ButtonEvent): void => {
    this.props.login.logIn();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 43):

for update: `event: React.ChangeEvent`
for submit: `event: React.FormEvent`
for click: `event: React.MouseEvent`

Answer (score 13):

I have the following in a `types.ts` file for html input, select, and textarea:

```
export type InputChangeEventHandler = React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
export type TextareaChangeEventHandler = React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement>
export type SelectChangeEventHandler = React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>
```

Then import them:

```
import { InputChangeEventHandler } from '../types'
```

Then use them:

```
const updateName: InputChangeEventHandler = (event) => {
  // Do something with `event.currentTarget.value`
}
const updateBio: TextareaChangeEventHandler = (event) => {
  // Do something with `event.currentTarget.value`
}
const updateSize: SelectChangeEventHandler = (event) => {
  // Do something with `event.currentTarget.value`
}
```

Then apply the functions on your markup (replacing `...` with other necessary props):

```
<input onChange={updateName} ... />
<textarea onChange={updateName} ... />
<select onChange={updateSize} ... >
  // ...
</select>
```

Comment: I guess it depends what you want to do (it's confusing), but for me I had to change it to `export type InputChangeEventHandler = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;` to be able to use `event.target.value`. Using `ChangeEventHandler` doesn't allow to use `event.target` as it's undefined.

Answer (score 12):

you can do like this in react

```
handleEvent = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>) => {
  const simpleInput = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  //for simple html input values
  const formInput = (e.target as HTMLFormElement).files[0];
  //for html form elements
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your example and
handleEvent: React.ReactEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => { ... }

Answer (score 10):

This is the recommended way as to the typescript compiler on 2022:

```
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
      console.log('click');
 };
```

No need to add void as return value as this is done automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for a solution to get an event and store something, in my case a HTML 5 element, on a `useState` here's my solution:

```js
const [anchorElement, setAnchorElement] = useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

const handleMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) : void => {
    setAnchorElement(event.currentTarget);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following have the same type:

```
let event1: { target: { value: any } };
let event2: { target: HTMLInputElement } };
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could just use

```
const handles = (e: React.UIEvent<'type of element', UIEvent>) => {
//do something
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.