# Typescript/React what's the correct type of the parameter for onKeyPress?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

Typescript 2.3.4, react 15.5.4 and react-bootstrap 0.31.0.

I have a `FormControl` and I want to do something when the user presses enter.

The control:

```
<FormControl
  name="keyword"
  type="text"
  value={this.state.keyword}
  onKeyPress={this.handleKeywordKeypress}
  onChange={(event: FormEvent<FormControlProps>) =>{
    this.setState({
      keyword: event.currentTarget.value as string
    });
  }}
/>
```

What should the definition of the parameter for `handleKeywordKeypress` be?

I can define it like this:

```
handleKeywordKeypress= (e: any) =>{
  log.debug("keypress: " + e.nativeEvent.code);
};
```

That will be called, and it will print `keypress: Enter` but what should the type of `e` be so that I can compare the value against (what?) to tell if Enter was pressed.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
handleKeywordKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<FormControl>) =>{
  if( e.key == 'Enter' ){
    if( this.isFormValid() ){
      this.handleCreateClicked();
    }
  }
};
```

The key<sub>(Ha ha)</sub> here, for me, was to specify `React.KeyboardEvent`, rather than `KeyboardEvent`.

Trolling around the React code, I was seeing definitions like:

```
type KeyboardEventHandler<T> = EventHandler<KeyboardEvent<T>>;
```

But didn't realise that when I was copy/pasting `KeyboardEvent` as the parameter type for my handler, the compiler was actually picking up the `KeyboardEvent` which is some kind of default type defined in the Typescript libraries somewhere (rather than the React definition).

Comment: If you wanted to simply specify KeyBoardEvent, you have to import it from React, that is all. `import {KeyboardEvent} from 'react';`

Answer (score 17):

Both of the answers above didnt solve my issue, it should be pretty simple and straightforward:

```
import { KeyboardEvent } from 'react';

const handleKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   // do stuff
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i don't know what is `FormControl`, and I believe `HTMLInputElement` should be the right one since other events are also borrowing from there.

Answer (score 6):

The type of `onKeyPress` should be `KeyboardEventHandler<T>`, which can be written in either of the following ways:

```
handleKeywordKeypress: KeyboardEventHandler<FormControl> = e => {
    // use e.keyCode in here
}
```

or

```
import { KeyboardEvent } from "react";
handleKeywordKeypress = (e: KeyboardEvent<FormControl>) => {
    // use e.keyCode in here
};
```

As you identified in your answer, if you go with the second option, you need to specifically use `KeyboardEvent` from React.

Note that the `keyCode` is directly available as a property on `e`; you don't need to access it via the `nativeEvent`.

Also, the generic type parameter `T` should be the `FormControl` component, rather than its props, so you should change your other handler too.

Comment: I don't see how your type declaration gets me access to the data I want without casting?  See my answer.

Comment: You're right, I have edited to improve my answer. Some of it is now quite similar to yours but hopefully there are still some extra useful things in there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me is a combination of two answers on this page, which only requires React is in scope.

Thanks **@Shorn** for `React.KeyboardEvent` **@underfrankenwood** for `HTMLInputElement`

```
import React from "react";
const handleKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   // ...
};
```