# React + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a properly typed callback function for the `onKeyPress` event.

I've tried giving either the function or the event various types, but I can't seem to get the event `e` to be recognized as having both the `key` field and the `target.value` field.

---

#### Case 1:

```
 const onKeyPress: React.KeyboardEventHandler = async (e) => {
     if (e.key === "Enter") {
         console.log(e.target.value);
     }
 };
```

Message:

> TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

#### Case 2:

```
 const onKeyPress = async (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
     if (e.key === "Enter") {
         console.log(e.target.value);
     }
 };
```

Message:

> TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

#### Case 3:

Turns out that even writing this simple JSX is going to throw out the same error:

```
 <input type="text" onKeyPress={(e) => {
     const key = e.key;
     const val = e.target.value;
 }}/>
```

---

#### Environment

From `package.json`:

> "@types/react": "^16.8.3"
>
> "react": "^16.8.2"
>
> "react-dom": "^16.8.2"

TypeScript `3.2.1`.

Any clue?

## Update

Accepted answer led me to this working piece of code:

```
 const onKeyPress = async (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
     if (e.key === "Enter") {
         console.log(`Received: ${e.currentTarget.value}`);
         await doAsyncStuff(e.currentTarget.value);
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript is right here, value does not exists on any html element. You need to be more precise about what kind of element it is.

If you replace your event by

```
React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>
```

it should work.

You also need to use `event.currentTarget` instead of `target`.

Comment: Tried that as well, updating OP to reflect this.

Comment: Looks like `event.currentTarget` *and* the event type you mentioned did the trick.

I had tried it `event.currentTarget` before, but I must have had some other type applied to the event and it failed.

It works now. Accepted as the right answer.

Comment: React resuses event so you can't access them in n asynchronous way, I think that's way it probably does not work with await.

Comment: I updated the OP with the final and working code I'm running. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `target` property refers to an element the event occurs on, not the element the handler was attached. That's why it only has properties common to all events, and `value` is not one of them.

In order to access the `value` property, you need to get it from the `currentTarget` property.

You can see this behaviour in the [React's type definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L997).

```
/**
 * currentTarget - a reference to the element on which the event listener is registered.
 *
 * target - a reference to the element from which the event was originally dispatched.
 * This might be a child element to the element on which the event listener is registered.
 * If you thought this should be `EventTarget & T`, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
 const onKeyPress = async (e: React.KeyboardEvent<FormControl>) => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
 };
```

OR

```
 const onKeyPress = async (e: KeyboardEventHandler<FormControl>) => {
     console.log(e.target.value);
 };
```

[Typescript/React what's the correct type of the parameter for onKeyPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462841/typescript-react-whats-the-correct-type-of-the-parameter-for-onkeypress)