# TypeScript error: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'Object' for event handler

Tags: typescript

I'm converting a React file to typescript, changing from `.js` to `.tsx`

I have event handlers such as

```
function handleTitle(e) {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
}
```

which I changed to

```
function handleTitle(e:object) {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
}
```

but with the change I am getting

```
TypeScript error: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'object'
```

I tried `e:object`, `e:array`, `e:any` and `e:string`

Comment: Why would you want to use the most generic types? Why TypeScript at all in this case?

Comment: Research your error e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44321326/3001761 or your task e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46462841/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e: React.YOUR_EVENT<YOUR_ELEMENT>`

For an "onChange" event on an input:

```
function handleTitle(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
}
```

DRY options:

Type the event

```
type OnChangeEvent = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>

function handleTitle(e: OnChangeEvent) {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
}
```

Type the function (parameter and return type)

```
type HandleTitleType = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void

const handleTitle: HandleTitleType = (e) => {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: nice.  and if I have three handlers, any suggestions on drying up?

Comment: What do you mean by drying up?

Comment: OP is asking you for refactoring advise (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself). But that totally depends on the actual code/setup and is nothing for a comment on an unrelated question...