# Property 'value' does not exist on 'EventTarget' in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

The following code in TypeScript with React is outputting the following error.

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class InputForm extends React.Component<any ,any> {
  state = {
    userInput: ''
  };

  handleUserInput = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value
    });
  }

  // Working code from 42081549
  // Not relevant to this project
  update = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    this.props.login[e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value
  }

  submitMessage = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.sendUserMessage(this.state.userInput)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="chat-input-form" onSubmit={this.submitMessage}>
        <input value={this.state.userInput} onChange={this.handleUserInput}/>
        <button type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }

}

export default InputForm;
```

I am currently using:

- "@types/react": "^16.0.40",
- "react": "^16.2.0",
- "typescript": "^2.7.2",

This could be considered a follow-up to [Typescript: React event types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types/42085792) however it is not a duplicate as working code provided in by [Nitzan Tomer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942852/nitzan-tomer) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42085792/1902408) is currently not working in my specific use case.

**EDIT** As mentioned above, NOT a duplicate of [Typescript: React event types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types), the solution provided in that question is not working in this case, and therefore could be a different cause.

My tsconfig.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",                           
    "sourceMap": true,                        
    "outDir": "./dist/",                      
    "strict": true,                        
    "noImplicitAny": true,                   
    "esModuleInterop": true                 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that you're using `e.target.value` instead of `e.currentTarget.value`.

As you can see in the [definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts):

```
interface SyntheticEvent<T> {
    ...
    currentTarget: EventTarget & T;
    ...
    target: EventTarget;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The update() method is giving the same error despite using e.currentTarget.

Comment: I'm compiling it with `typescript@2.7.2` and `@types/react@16.0.40` and it compiles just fine when I make the fix in my answer.  Maybe you have something weird in your environment.  Create a new directory, and install things there from fresh, then make sure you compile it from there: `./node_modules/.bin/tsc ...` and see if there's a change.

Comment: Same issue in a fresh directory with InputForm.tsx as the only file, running the command `/node_modules/.bin/tsc InputForm.tsx --jsx react` with the same version numbers as above.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Your code compiles just fine for me, with the same versions for ts and the react types.  It must be something in your environment that is messed up, but I don't know what.

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding but when I open up the type definitions (@Types/react/global.d.ts) the interface for EventTarget is an empty object.

If I was amend this to an interface where value is expected as string the error goes away.

Am I importing the type definitions incorrectly?

Comment: `EventTarget` isn't what you need, notice that the `currentTarget` property is of type `EventTarget & T`.  In your case, `T` is `HTMLFormElement` which has the property `value`.

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate a bit on Nitzan Tomer's answer...

You *used* to be able to use `e.target.value` in this way where target would be generic, in this case: `HTMLInputElement`. The code was reverted to make `e.currentTarget` generic and make `e.target` not generic (hard-coded to EventTarget). EventTarget doesn't have a value attribute.

The reason lies in the difference between `currentTarget` and `target`. When you refer to `target`, you refer to the element which triggered the event. If you have a button, with some icon in it. If the icon is directly clicked, then it would be the target. At compile time, you cannot know what element type will trigger the click, but you can know which element the eventListener is registered on. Thus `currentTarget` is generic.

Further, `target` is rarely what you want. You typically want the element, where you attached the eventListener.

The [Github comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11508#issuecomment-256045682) providing the above rationale.
The [Github PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239) where target was made /not/ generic.

Comment: yes but this shouldn't be a thing when explicitly using `React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>` , there is no way `target` differs from `currentTarget`