# Property does not exist on type - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Created custom `Form` component which supposed to change its `data` when child inputs change.

Long story short:

[image]

In the current context `currentTarget` is the form, `target` is the input which triggered the event. `target` is exactly what I need - since I can then update the data:

```
this.setState({
  data: {
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

- Wrong event type?
- Any way to cast in TypeScript (already tried)?
- Wrong approach?

---

**EDIT:** something like this works, but this is just wrong:

handleChange(e: React.FormEvent) {
    let foo: any = e;
    this.setState({
      data: {
        [foo.target.name]: foo.target.value
      }
    });
  }

Comment: Have you tried to cast the `e.target` to `(<HTMLFormElement>e.target).name`? This is just a long shoot, I didn't tried that.

Comment: It was the right way of thinking. Posted the solution - it seems to do the same but in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimenting:

`handleChange(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    let name: string = (e.target as HTMLFormElement).name;
    let value: string = (e.target as HTMLFormElement).value;
    this.setState({
      data: {
        [name]: value
      }
  });`

It makes sense, since in this case the `HTMLInputElement` (`target`) is accessed as `HTMLFormElement` (listener).

May be there is more elegant solution but this kinda works.

Comment: Also an option to destructure: `const { value }: { value: string } = (event.target as HTMLFormElement).myNameOfInput;`

Answer (score 1):

Change the params to `handleChange(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)` and use `e.currentTarget.name`.

@thurt explain why in this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types), I also found some helpful comments in the type definition file [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L442).

Answer (score 0):

How do you invoke your function handleChange?

i guess you are doing something like this:

```
onChange={this.handleChange()}
```

but you must do it:

```
onChange={this.handleChange)}
```

In fact, you have to pass the reference of the function, and not to invoke the function