# What type of event should I set this method to?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What type of event should I set the `setEndpointState` method of this component to. I tried setting it to `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` but then I get a type error in the setState function saying that I am missing props `name`, `hostname` and `description`. Is the type of the event wrong or is there a way to write the setState function differently?

```
import * as React from "react";
import EditBasicInfoForm from "./EditBasicInfoForm";
import { Endpoint } from "../../Endpoints/model";

interface EditBasicInfoProps {
  editBasicInfo: (endpoint: Endpoint) => void;
  ocid: string;
}

interface EditBasicInfoState {
  name: string;
  hostname: string;
  description: string;
}

export class EditBasicInfo extends React.Component<EditBasicInfoProps & EditBasicInfoState, EditBasicInfoState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      hostname: "",
      description: ""
    };

    this.setEndpointState = this.setEndpointState.bind(this);
    this.editBasicInfo = this.editBasicInfo.bind(this);
  }

  public setEndpointState(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void {
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  public editBasicInfo(): void {
    const endpoint: any = {
      name: this.state.name,
      hostname: this.state.hostname,
      description: this.state.description,
      ocid: this.props.ocid,
    };

    this.props.editBasicInfo(endpoint);
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <>
        <EditBasicInfoForm
          name={this.state.name}
          hostname={this.state.hostname}
          description={this.state.description}
          handleChange={this.setEndpointState}
          handleSubmit={this.editBasicInfo}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default EditBasicInfo;
```

Comment: its a SyntheticEvent. Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: React event types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types)

Comment: I changed it to ```public setEndpointState(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log(e.type);
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }``` but I am still getting the same error in the setState call.

Comment: What does `EditBasicInfoForm` look like? What triggers the `handleChange`?

Answer (score 0):

Notice - your state implements the interface `EditBasicInfoState`, hence every time you `setState`, it expects a full state that implements that interface to be provided.

You are currently providing it with an object that uses the `name` as a dynamic key (which probably doesn't exist even on your state), and you are missing the rest of the fields.

See if setting the state with this object `{name: '', hostname: '', description: ''}` removes the error, just to be sure this is indeed the problem.

If this indeed solves your problem, I suggest going back to the meaning of interfaces in Typescript, and reading about `Partial`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Thanks for all the help!

```
public setEndpointState(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```