# Accessing currentTime on SyntheticEvent target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

In vanilla react you get `currentTime` like

```
(e) => e.target.currentTime
```

Doing the above in typescript ^3.1.6 results in

> Property 'currentTime' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

[`SyntheticEvent`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L572) doesn't seem to list `EventTarget` anywhere, so I don't know how to get `currentTime`. The Typescript lib shows it's [already defined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L7052) and my tsconfig (generated via [this fork](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript)) looks like

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
}
```

Deps:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react-router": "^4.4.0",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
  "@types/node": "^10.12.2",
  "@types/react": "^16.4.18",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
  "typescript": "^3.1.6"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types)

> What you need to do is to cast the target to the specific element type with the properties you need.

So to get `currentTime` you need to do

```
(e: React.SyntheticEvent): void => {
  const { currentTime } : { currentTime: number } = e.target as HTMLMediaElement;
}
```