# React Hooks TypeScript event and state types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What are the types of React.js's state and event?

In my code below, I can only make it work by using `type: any` but it's just a hack. How can I use the right types for them?

In my custom hooks:

If I use `function useFormFields(initialState: object)`, I get:

```
// value={inputs.item} error:
Property 'item' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
// onChange function error:
(JSX attribute) onChange: object
No overload matches this call.
```

If I use `function(event: React.FormEvent)` (which is true), I have this error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)
```

If I use `function(event: object)`, I have this error:

```
Property 'target' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
```

That's odd because below I use `const handleSubmitItem = (event: React.FormEvent)` and it works.

The answers I've found (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types)) don't work for me because `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import AddShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddShoppingCart';

/**
 * Custom hooks for input fields.
 * @param initialState initialState for Input Fields
 */
function useFormFields(initialState: any) {
    const [inputs, setValues] = useState(initialState);

    return [
        inputs,
        function(event: any) {
            setValues({
                ...inputs,
                [event.target.id]: event.target.value
            });
        }
    ];
}

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
    const [inputs, handleInputChange] = useFormFields({
        item: '',
        quantity: '',
        store: ''
    });

    const handleSubmitItem = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(inputs);
    };

    return (
        <form 
            className={classes.root} 
            noValidate autoComplete="off"
            onSubmit={handleSubmitItem}
        >
            <div>
                <TextField 
                    required id="item" 
                    label="Item" 
                    value={inputs.item}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="quantity"
                    label="Quantity"
                    type="number"
                    value={inputs.quantity}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                />
                <TextField 
                    id="store" 
                    label="Store" 
                    type="search"
                    value={inputs.store}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <IconButton 
                    type="submit"
                    color="primary" 
                    aria-label="add to shopping cart"
                >
                    <AddShoppingCartIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some corrections in the solution that you found. 
Hope it helps!

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import AddShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddShoppingCart';

/**
 * Custom hooks for input fields.
 * @param initialState initialState for Input Fields
 */

export interface MyModel {
    item: string
    quantity: string
    store: string
}

function useFormFields<T>(initialState: T): [T, (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>) => void] {
    const [inputs, setValues] = useState<T>(initialState);

    return [
        inputs,
        function (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>) {
            setValues({
                ...inputs,
                [event.target.id]: event.target.value
            });
        }
    ];
}

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
    const [inputs, handleInputChange] = useFormFields<MyModel>({
        item: '',
        quantity: '',
        store: ''
    });

    const handleSubmitItem = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(inputs);
    };

    return (
        <form 
            className={classes.root} 
            noValidate autoComplete="off"
            onSubmit={handleSubmitItem}
        >
            <div>
                <TextField 
                    required id="item" 
                    label="Item" 
                    value={inputs.item}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="quantity"
                    label="Quantity"
                    type="number"
                    value={inputs.quantity}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                />
                <TextField 
                    id="store" 
                    label="Store" 
                    type="search"
                    value={inputs.store}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <IconButton 
                    type="submit"
                    color="primary" 
                    aria-label="add to shopping cart"
                >
                    <AddShoppingCartIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nightElf, let me try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since every component may be different you need to define the state and props types by yourself. There are some basic types defined for react (because every component may have `children` for example) but as i said, you will need to define your own types.

An example for a functional component:

```
const App: React.FC<{ message: string }> = ({ message }) => (
  <div>{message}</div>
);
```

The example above could also be written like so:

```
type MyType = { message: string }
const App: React.FC<MyType> = ({ message }) => (
  <div>{message}</div>
);
```

further reading here:

https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#section-2-getting-started

Comment: Thank you @messerbill, let me try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Generals! the answer!

hope it helps!

```js
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import AddShoppingCartIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddShoppingCart';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export interface MyModel {
    item: string;
    quantity: string;
    store: string;
 }

/**
 * Custom hooks for input fields.
 * @param initialState initialState for Input Fields
 **/
function useFormFields<T>(initialState: T) {
    const [inputs, setValues] = useState(initialState);

    return [
        inputs,
        function(event: React.FormEvent) {
            const {name, value} = event.currentTarget;
            setValues({
                ...inputs,
                [name]: value
            });
        }
    ];
}

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
    const [inputs, handleInputChange] = useFormFields<MyModel>({
        item: '',
        quantity: '',
        store: '',
    });

    const handleSubmitItem = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        /***
           make sure to have whatever attribute you want in the "html tag"
        */
        const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
        console.log(inputs);
    };

    return (
        <form
            className={classes.root}
            noValidate autoComplete="off"
        >
            <div>
                <TextField
                    required id="item"
                    label="Item"
                    name="Item"
                    value={inputs.item}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="quantity"
                    label="Quantity"
                    name="Quantity"
                    type="number"
                    value={inputs.quantity}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="store"
                    label="Store"
                    name="Store"
                    type="search"
                    value={inputs.store}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <IconButton
                    type="button"
                    color="primary"
                    aria-label="add to shopping cart"
                    onClick={handleSubmitItem}
                >
                    <AddShoppingCartIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Emesto, let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for the long gap. Your answer returns these errors: `property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & Element'.` If I keep `[event.target.id]: event.target.value`, it returns: `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`