# Preserve hook types when using array destructuring

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a simple hook to export animation helper and element ref i.e.

```
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { useRef } from 'react';

export function useTween<R extends gsap.TweenTarget>(vars: gsap.TweenVars['pixi']) {
  const tweenRef = useRef<R>(null);
  const tween = gsap.to(tweenRef.current, { pixi: vars });

  return [tween, tweenRef];
}
```

What matters here is that returned array has types, however when I use it in another component i.e.

```
const [textTween, textRef] = useTween<Text>({ scale: 2 });
```

now `textTween` and `textRef` both have type of `any`, I was under impression that these types would be preserved, but am I missing something here?

Comment: you can try adding return type to the hook, or what could be even better to create a function type and then just use it.
This could be the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137706/react-hooks-typescript-event-and-state-types

Answer (score 1):

you are forgetting to specify return type of your function:

```
export function useTween<R extends gsap.TweenTarget>(vars: gsap.TweenVars['pixi']): [gsap.TweenTarget, gsap.TweenTarget] {
```