# JS phone format change to TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is the JS I have trying to convert to TS:

```
/**
 * @param {string} value The value to be formatted into a phone number
 * @returns {string}
 */
export const formatPhoneString = (value) => {
const areaCode = value.substr(0, 3);
const prefix = value.substr(3, 3);
const suffix = value.substr(6, 4);
const output = `(${areaCode}) ${prefix}-${suffix}`;

return output;
};

/**
* Event handler for a phone number input to update the phone number's formatting
* @param {object} event js event object
*/
export const formatPhoneNumber = (event) => {
const targetElement = event.target;

// Get the value and remove all of the non-digit characters
const value = targetElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

if (value.length === 10) {
    const output = formatPhoneString(value);

    // Update the value of the input
    targetElement.value = output;
}`enter code here`
};
```

When I try to pull this into new ts file getting type error for "event" What is the syntax for the event object in TS?

Comment: What type did you set? There is an Event type in TS. (Don't know the full type of the top of my head, but shouldn't be hard to find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set it to type Event, KeyboardEvent, MouseEvent, etc

```
export const formatPhoneNumber = (event: Event) => {

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081549/typescript-react-event-types

Comment: Thanks That helped with my first issue. Second question is how to replace "targetElement.value". Getting error Value not found on Event