# Property 'value' does not exist on type EventTarget in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So the following code is in Angular 4 and I can't figure out why it doesn't work the way as expected.

Here is a snippet of my handler:

```
onUpdatingServerName(event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
  this.newserverName = event.target.value; //this wont work
}
```

HTML element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onUpdatingServerName($event)">
```

The code gives me the error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

But as it can be seen in the `console.log` that value does exist on the `event.target`.

Comment: we can use (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value

Comment: Bro, I struggled with this for hours, you simply have to remove the type from the method. onUpdatingServerName(event);

Comment: @Fatih esLint will automatically add it back or complain and refuse to compile. Can't change this rule for a project with multiple developers.

Comment: @RinandLen You could maybe try using the any type

Answer (score 482, accepted):

`event.target` here is an `HTMLElement` which is the parent of all HTML elements, but isn't guaranteed to have the property `value`. TypeScript detects this and throws the error. Cast `event.target` to the appropriate HTML element to ensure it is `HTMLInputElement` which does have a `value` property:

```
(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
```

Per [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#!#type-the--*event*):

> #### Type the *`$event`*
>
> The example above casts the `$event` as an `any` type. That simplifies the code at a cost. There is no type information that could reveal properties of the event object and prevent silly mistakes.
>
> [...]
>
> The `$event` is now a specific `KeyboardEvent`. **Not all elements have a `value` property so it casts `target` to an input element.**

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: A bit cleaner syntax `var element = ev.target as HTMLElement`

Comment: For me, HTMLInputElement worked instead of HTMLElement as HTMLElement  does not have value in the interface.

Comment: The best approach, in my opinion, is having `onFieldUpdate(event: { target: HTMLInputElement }) {` in the called function. See my answer below.

Comment: For Angular 9 use "as" syntax. `event.target as HtmlInputlement`

Comment: @Prescol @Alessandro_russo - Safer would be:

`event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement ? event.target.value : undefined`

Answer (score 188):

Passing HTMLInputElement as a generic to the event type should work too:

```
onUpdatingServerName(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  console.log(event);
  this.newserverName = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the function is called from i.e. an `onChange` proeperty handler reference in React code though. The react handler does not expect the type to be set for the React.ChangeEvent and will show a typing error. I had to revert to (a variant of) the selected answer instead, with a cast: `(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value`.

Comment: This seemed to work for me fine in a React component. Maybe it's the version of React? We're currently on 16.8.*.

Comment: Note that your answer is only relevant to react. The OP was asking about angular.

Comment: I like this approach better than the casting , but it's true that sometimes we use onBlur or onKeyDown , things like tha

Answer (score 92):

Here's another fix that works for me:

`(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value`

That should get rid of the error by letting TS know that `event.target` is an `HTMLInputElement`, which inherently has a `value`. Before specifying, TS likely only knew that `event` alone was an `HTMLInputElement`, thus according to TS the keyed-in `target` was some randomly mapped value that could be anything.

Comment: This was really helpful in React where it tried to interpret <HTMLInputElement> as JSX.

Answer (score 36):

I was looking for a solution to a similar TypeScript error with React:

> Property 'dataset' does not exist on type EventTarget in TypeScript

I wanted to get to `event.target.dataset` of a clicked button element in React:

```
<button
  onClick={onClickHandler}
  data-index="4"
  data-name="Foo Bar"
>
  Delete Candidate
</button>
```

Here is how I was able to get the `dataset` value to "exist" via TypeScript:

```
const onClickHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  const { name, index } = (event.target as HTMLButtonElement).dataset
  console.log({ name, index })
  // do stuff with name and index…
}
```

Comment: Question is tagged as Angular so a React answer seems off topic.

Comment: Regardless… it has multiple up votes, thus this answer has been helpful to others.

Comment: Works like a charm. `onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
              setTextFilter(event.target.value);
            }}`

Answer (score 29):

In template -

```
`(keyup)="value2=$any($event.target).value"`
```

in component -

```
getInput(event: Event) {
  this.value1 = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

The way I do it is the following (better than type assertion imho):

```js
onFieldUpdate(event: { target: HTMLInputElement }) {
  this.$emit('onFieldUpdate', event.target.value);
}
```

This assumes you are only interested in the `target` property, which is the most common case. If you need to access the other properties of `event`, a more comprehensive solution involves using the `&` type intersection operator:

```js
event: Event & { target: HTMLInputElement }
```

This is a Vue.js version but the concept applies to all frameworks. Obviously you can go more specific and instead of using a general `HTMLInputElement` you can use e.g. `HTMLTextAreaElement` for textareas.

Comment: This should be up there with the best answer thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

This works for me in ANGULAR HTML Component !!

```
$any($event.target).value
```

Source Link:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-angular/

Comment: This works for me in Angular 16. <3

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem, use the $any typecast function `($any($event.target).value)` to stop the type checking in the template.

Read more [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-angular/).

Answer (score 7):

**React** has some interface like `ChangeEvent` for `onChange`, `FormEvent` for  `onSubmit` etc

I was also trying to do similar like this below solution worked for me

```
handleChange (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
}


<input 
   autoFocus
   value={this.state.account.username}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   id="username" 
   type="text" 
   className="form-control" 
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `event.target.value` prop with onChange handler if not you could see :

```
index.js:1437 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

Or If you want to use other handler than onChange, use `event.currentTarget.value`

Answer (score 2):

Declare interface

```typescript
export interface HTMLInputEvent extends Event {
  target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
}
```

which can be re-used as a type for different input events

```typescript
public onChange(event: HTMLInputEvent) {
  const value = event.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***Please try this one***

```
<input type = 'text' [value] = 'value' (input) = 'data = $any($event.target).value'>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also create your own interface as well.

```
    export interface UserEvent {
      target: HTMLInputElement;
    }

       ...

    onUpdatingServerName(event: UserEvent) {
      .....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly parse it into "HTMLInputElement" and then access 'value'

```
onUpdatingServerName(event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
  this.newserverName = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, TypeScript has been always strictly on the element data type. So, You can't directly access attributes of an element without specifying its data type. The `event.target` is an `HTMLElement` which is the parent of all HTML elements, but isn't guaranteed to have the property **value**.

So, we need to typecast the variable `event.target` then only we can access the value attribute from it.

```
OnUpdatingServerName (event: Event) {
  console.log(event);
  var element = event.target as HTMLElement
  this.newserverName = element.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a utility type:

```typescript
interface MyEvent<T extends EventTarget> extends Omit<Event, 'target'> {
  target: T;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```typescript
function onChange({ target: { value } }: MyEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  doSomethingWith(value);
}
```

Answer (score -7):

Try code below:

```
  console.log(event['target'].value)
```

it works for me :-)

Comment: better remove your answer

Answer (score -15):

add any type to event

```
event: any
```

example

```
[element].addEvenListener('mousemove', (event: any) =>{
//CODE//
} )
```

what happens is that typescript adds "event" (click in this case) as Event type and for some reason it doesn't recognize some properties. Adding it of type any no longer exists this problem, this works for any `document.[Property]`

Comment: Welcome on the SO! Why and how? Please explain.

Comment: you may remove your answer if it get minused hardly

Comment: By adding any will give warning on compile-time, and not recommended to use any in TS file, otherwise the purpose of using ts file is dying.

Comment: @ZeeshanSafdar I agree that you shouldn't do what @dylanroman03 has done here, however `any` is perfectly fine to use in cases where the object can in fact be anything. In general, if you know what the object's properties are (like we do here), you shouldn't be using `any`. If the object can have any properties, you should use `any`.