# Angular value of multiple input field

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Page have multiple input field.

```
<div class="form-group w-100">
        <label class="col-md-3 text-left" for="">Box 2</label>
    <input
      class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
      [value]="MenuBox2"
      [style.background]="MenuBox2"
      [(colorPicker)]="MenuBox2"
      (colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group w-100">
    <label class="col-md-3 text-left" for="">Box 2 Text</label>

      class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
      [value]="MenuBox2Text"
      [style.background]="MenuBox2Text"
      [(colorPicker)]="MenuBox2Text"
      (colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group w-100">
    <label class="col-md-3 text-left" for="">Box 2 Hover Text</label>
    <input
      class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
      [value]="MenuBox2Hover"
      [style.background]="MenuBox2Hover"
      [(colorPicker)]="MenuBox2Hover"
      (colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"
    />
  </div>
```

All these field are color picker using `ngx-color-picker` package.
I am trying to get the value of each input field and store in `firestore`.

```
updateFirestoreColor(event: any) {
   this.afs.collection('General').doc('colors').update(event);
}
```

**Problem**
What is the best solution to use single function for all fields, to get the value of respected field.

TIA

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any functions, just use Reactive forms like shown below instead of [value] for all inputs respectivly.

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="form-group w-100" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <label class="col-md-3 text-left" for="">Box 2</label>
    <input
      class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
      formControlName="MenuBox2"
      [style.background]="MenuBox2"
      [(colorPicker)]="MenuBox2"
      (colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group w-100">
    <label class="col-md-3 text-left" for="">Box 2 Text</label>

      class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
      formControlName="MenuBox2Text"
      [style.background]="MenuBox2Text"
      [(colorPicker)]="MenuBox2Text"
      (colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group w-100">
    <label class="col-md-3 text-left" for="">Box 2 Hover Text</label>
    <input
      class="form-control ml-2 mr-2"
      formControlName ="MenuBox2Hover"
      [style.background]="MenuBox2Hover"
      [(colorPicker)]="MenuBox2Hover"
      (colorPickerChange)="updateFirestoreColor($event)"
    />
  </div>
```

TS file:

```
form:FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit(){
 this.form = this.fb.group({
   MenuBox2:'',
   MenuBox2Text:'',
   MenuBox2Hover:'',
 })

}

onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.form.value)//Firebase call
}
```

Comment: using Reactive-Forms, but once the value of text field change, it shows null value

Answer (score -1):

As you asked **What is the best solution to use a single function for all fields?**
so, for that, you can try something like this:

```
updateFirestoreColor(event: any) {
   var value= (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value
   this.afs.collection('General').doc('colors').update(value);
}
```

Comment: But it works fine for me as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321326/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-in-typescript