# StencilJs value does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I want to set the value of an ion-input field when the page is loaded.
I'm trying to get the element from the `shadowDom` using the `shadowRoot querySelector`.
It is a **stencil** project with **ionic**. The component uses the `shadowDOM`.
When I try to get the value my IDE says:

[image: IDE error message]

The nameEl:

`const nameEl = this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name');`

The value will be set correctly, but I was wondering how I could fix this error message.

**EDIT:**
Answer as suggested by Ash is correct. And like Ash mentioned there are two ways of implementing this solution. But I was wondering if there is any difference between the solutions?

`const nameEl = this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name') as HTMLInputElement;`

or

`const nameEl: HTMLInputElement = this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name');`

**EDIT:**
The solution of course also work as one-liners as in Ash his example.
`(this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name') as HTMLInputElement).value`

And in my case the input is a ionic input:
`(this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name') as HTMLIonInputElement).value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the value works as you said but the reason for the error is as the message says `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'`. To phrase it differently to help you understand, the message is saying:

- You have something of type `Element`
- The `value` property does not exist on the type definition for that something

Therefore you need to either correct the code to get the right type of element or in your case tell the code what to expect.

```js
(<HTMLInputElement>nameEl).value
// OR
(nameEl as HTMLElement).value
```

The above snippets were taken from the related questions below and updated to match your variable names.

I answered here because you mentioned Stencil but is not related to the issues, however this question is a duplicate and answers for similar questions can be found at [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget) and [Property 'value' does not exist on type EventTarget in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321326/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-in-typescript/44321394)