# Angular currentTarget acess properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to access the left offSet with the following in angular.

```
currentTarget.offsetLeft
```

It says that offsetLeft does not exist.

Here is a part of the code I am working on.

```
onRightClick(event: MouseEvent) {


      /*const origin = {
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
      };*/
       console.log('clientX'+ event.clientX);
       console.log('clientY'+event.clientY);
       console.log('pageX'+event.pageX);
       console.log('pageY'+event.pageY);
       console.log('screenX'+event.screenX);
       console.log('screenY'+event.screenY);
       console.log('offsetX'+event.offsetX);
       console.log('offsetY'+event.offsetY);
       const elm = event.currentTarget;
       this.x = (event.currentTarget.offsetLeft);
       this.y = (event.currentTarget.offsetTop); // - (event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.offsetLeft));

...}
```

Comment: What is currentTarget?

Comment: The target is the element which has raised an event

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321326/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-in-typescript/44321394