# Which is the right type for an event passed to the onKeyPressed function in React with MaterialUI and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

In a React app, where I use Typescript and MaterialUI, I have a TextField.

I would like to get access to the `input` html element value when `enter` is pressed.

So I have the following code

```
  const keyPress = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      console.log("Do login", e.target.value);
    }
  };
```

and somewhere in the returned React tree I have this

```
<TextField onKeyPress={keyPress} />
```

This code works, bu my problem is that I do not understand how to define the right type for the event `e` passed to the function `keyPressed`.

According to what VSCode intellisense is suggesting when I hover over `onKeyPress` prop, I understand I should use `KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>`, but the problem is that then I get an error which says `Type 'KeyboardEvent' is not generic`.

What I am doing wrong?

By the way, everything works fine if I give the event the type `e: { key: string; target: any }`, but still it is interesting to understand what I am doing wrong when I try to follow the right way.

**UPDATE**

After some more research, it seems that the event passed to `keyPressed` function is of type `KeyboardEvent` and that its `target` property is of type `EventTarget`.

Looking at the definition of `EventTarget` in `global.d.ts` in `React` package, then I see that it is the empty interface.

In the comments of `global.d.ts` I read also that "Warning: all of these interfaces are empty. If you want type definitions for various properties
(such as HTMLInputElement.prototype.value), you need to add `--lib DOM` (via command line or tsconfig.json).". But my `tsconfig.json` actually contains `DOM` in the libraries (the property is `"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],`).

Again, I can make things work, but I would like to understand how to get a clean type for that event.

Comment: You can see that right in your editor by doing `CTRL+click` on `onKeyPress` attribure which will take you to the `*.d.ts` file of material-ui.

Comment: @Ajeet Shah  Thanks for your response, but but your suggestion is not so straightforward, at least for me. `onKeyPress` is of type `KeyboardEventHandler<T>`. If I look at `KeyboardEventHandler<T>` I see that it is defined as `EventHandler<KeyboardEvent<T>>`. Then I look at `EventHandler<KeyboardEvent<T>>` which is defined as `EventHandler<E extends SyntheticEvent<any>> = { bivarianceHack(event: E): void }["bivarianceHack"];`. Now things are getting a bit complicated for me to follow. The end result is that I am not ble to give a clean type to the event passed to the `keyPress` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define typing for `onKeyPress` handler i.e. `keyPress` as:

```
import { KeyboardEvent, EventHandler } from 'react'

const keyPress: EventHandler<KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>> = (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('Do login', (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
  }
}

<TextField id="id" label="Name" onKeyPress={keyPress} />
```

Typescript will give you below error ...

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Another post on this error: [Property 'value' does not exist on type EventTarget in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44321326/2873538)

... when you access value - `e.target.value` though the `value` exists, so you can suppress this error by casting it as `HTMLInputElement` as shown above.

In my opinion, you are trying to access `e.key`, not the `e.target.value` in `onKeyPress` handler; as you are most likely to do that in `onChange` handler.

---

Same but, maybe, shorter form:

```
type KeyPressType<T = Element> = EventHandler<KeyboardEvent<T>>

const keyPress: KeyPressType<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('Do login', (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
  }
}
```

---

**Question:** What's the type of `e`?

**Answer:** It is `KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>`