# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' in HTML

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to deploy my app and I encounter this error : "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

search.page.html

```
  <ion-searchbar

  (search)="searchForIsland($event.target.value)"

     showCancelButton="focus"

     >

  </ion-searchbar>

</form>
```

When I'm running the project everything is working fine so is there something else that I can use instead of "value" in order to be able to deploy the project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'value' does not exist on type EventTarget in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321326/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-in-typescript)

Comment: Please do a little searching for the error before asking, it is appreciated. See [ask] for more tips on how the site works.