# Angular property 'parentNode' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent

I'm trying to reach a parent of some element:

`let t = e.target.parentNode`

but i have this Error: `Property 'parentNode' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`

I've tried with `<Element>e.target.parentNode` but this also not gives me any results. Can anybody help?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you try logging `e.target` on the console?

Comment: Yes and i have an HTML element

Comment: Maybe you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900077/why-is-event-target-not-element-in-typescript)

Answer (score 23):

I had to wrap the typecasting in parentheses:

```
let parent = ( <HTMLElement>event.target ).parentElement;
```

or using parentNode:

```
let parent = ( <HTMLElement>( <HTMLElement>event.target ).parentNode );
```

Comment: Awsome it worked