# Angular equivalent to event target matches

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, dom-events

I'm trying to transfer a dropdown menu from Javascript to Typescript to use in my Angular project. I can't figure out how to simulate event.target.matches though, which is giving me some problems. Is there a Typescript equivalent that is easy to implement?

Here's the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Test Site Please Ignore';
  currentUser: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.currentUser=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
  }
  dropfunction(variable){
    var dropdowns=document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
    var thisElement=document.getElementById(variable);
    thisElement.classList.toggle("show");
  };
  onClickedOutside(e: Event) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')){
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
              openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me the error: "[ts] Property 'matches' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'." (triggered by the if statement of onClickedOutside.

Edit, the template code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)" (click)="dropfunction('myDropdown0')" id="dropbtn0" class="dropbtn">Home</button>
<div id="myDropdown0" class="dropdown-content">
    <a routerLink="/"> Index </a>
    <a routerLink="/profile">Profile</a>
    <div *ngIf="currentUser">
      <a routerLink="/login">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!currentUser">
      <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      <a routerLink="/register">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're using an old version of TypeScript
The `matches` methods on elements is implemented in the newer versions of TypeScript. You can see this [github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5813) that referenced the issue.

To solve it:

- Update to the latest version of TypeScript

Or

- You can change your condition with `matches` and use `classList.contains()` instead.

```js
 if(!e.target.classList.contains('dropbtn'))
```

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.2, I think i must be doing something else wrong here, I'll add the template code in an edit, maybe the problem lies there. Because I can't add .classList to it either.

Comment: A little bit of a nitpick here, you don't want the `.` that denotes a class here, you'd want just `dropbtn` inside your contains check for an element that has a class of `dropbtn`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
if( !e.target.value === '.dropbtn')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it [with the help of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900077/why-is-event-target-not-element-in-typescript). Had to set event.target to an element.

Working:

```
onClickedOutside(e: Event) {
var ele=<Element>e.target;
if (!ele.matches('.dropbtn')){
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
  }
}
```

}