# EventTarget is not able to access classList

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to make an expansion panel expand only when clinking the arrow, but when I try to compile it, this function

```
private _isExpansionIndicator(target: EventTarget): boolean {
    const expansionIndicatorClass = 'mat-expansion-indicator';
    return (target.classList && target.classList.contains(expansionIndicatorClass) );
  }
```

returns the following error:

```
"Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'"
```

Any clues how do I get past this error or do you know any other workaround to acheive the same functionality?

I got it working on stackblitz with no errors...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-material-e6sh1r

Comment: Can you please show the relevant portion of your template?

Comment: No. The thing is working on stackblitz, but it doesn't compile locally....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `console.log({event});` and `console.log({target});`, you can see the following :

- The `EventTarget` is actually `MouseEvent`, and the `target` property is not of a fixed type. You can see this post to know more on the subject : [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900077/why-is-event-target-not-element-in-typescript)
- Since the target element is a `span`, you can use with TypeScript the `HTMLSpanElement` type to help you for that.

Here is imo a cleaner solution of what is proposed as an alternative answer :

```
  expandPanel(matExpansionPanel: any, event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log({event});

    if (!this._isExpansionIndicator(event.target as HTMLSpanElement)) {
      matExpansionPanel.close();
    }
  }

   private _isExpansionIndicator(target: HTMLSpanElement): boolean {
    console.log({target});
    const expansionIndicatorClass = 'mat-expansion-indicator';
    return (target.classList && target.classList.contains(expansionIndicatorClass) );
  }
```

Comment: In fact, I like your approach better than what I currently have... I think I will go with that! Thank you!

Comment: @gothaf I also think this is more appropriate, IMO you should remove accepted from my answer and mark this answer as accepted. upvoted this answer.

Comment: Ok @Plochie.. Only because you say so... :)

Comment: Thank you guys!! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

You need to typecast 'EventTarget' to `Element`, change function as follows,

```js
private _isExpansionIndicator(target: EventTarget): boolean {
    const expansionIndicatorClass = 'mat-expansion-indicator';
    return ((<Element>target).classList && (<Element>target).classList.contains(expansionIndicatorClass) );
}
```