# Why can't I get the ID of an event.target in React using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom-events, mouseclick-event

In React 18.2 with TypeScript I have:

```js
export default function App() {
  const clikHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    console.log(event.target.id); // Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="parent" onClick={clikHandler}>
        <div id="child"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But `id` does exist.
Even if I use `HTMLDivElement` it still complains.

The event is in a parent DIV element and I want to get the ID of the child element that was clicked.

Comment: You would have to cast it or check if it's an element first.

Comment: [Why isn't `Event.target` an `HTMLElement`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900856/18244921)